# How to find out the flutter application crash logs?

Tags: flutter, dart

My flutter application is crashed when launching it in windows. I need to find out the crash logs to resolve the problem. But I can't able to do it. Is there a way to find out the flutter application crash logs?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are developing flutter web application. As a document from Flutter you can use [Report errors to a service](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/maintenance/error-reporting). That are using [Sentry](https://pub.dev/packages/sentry). Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [firebase_crashlytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics) to record crash of your application.

Comment: I did not use firebase in my application. Even if, Can I able to get crash logs for my app by using it?

Comment: Yes you can record your app crash log if you use firebase crashlytics and you can see all crash report in firebase console including device info and and file location which cause to issue

Answer (score 0):

No Crashlytics doesn't record OOM Crash
as per https://twitter.com/Arzhannikov_A/status/1073194994134065152
correct me if I'm wrong